# Normalizing data in jq

Tags: data-manipulation, jq

Imagine data that looks something like:

```
[{
    "names": {
        "official_full": "John Smith",
        "nickname": "Johnny"
    },
    "positions": [{
        "start": "1993-01-05",
        "end": "2002-12-03",
        "title": "Executive VP of Operations",
        "city": "Winnipeg",
        "state": "Michigan"
    }, ...]
}, ...]
```

Is it possible in jq to normalize the data like below?

```
{
    people: [{
        "full_name": "John Smith"
    }, ...],

    terms: [{
        "start": "1993-01-05",
        "end": "2002-12-03",
        "person": 1,
        "job": 0
    }, ...],

    jobs: [{
        "title": "Executive VP of Operations",
        "location": 0
    }, ...],

    locations: [{
        "city": "Winnipeg",
        "state": "Michigan"
    }, ...]
}
```

I'm kind of new to jq so I don't know where to really begin. My main issue is how to create an object beforehand that would then be populated as I iterate through the passed in json i.e.

```
{
    people: [],
    terms: [],
    jobs: [],
    locations: []
}
```

and how do I get the index of an appended object?

I'm not sure if this is even easy to do with jq. I might just write a nodejs script using normalizrjs.

Another issue is making sure an object such as a `job` or `location` isn't duplicated so I'd want to make sure there isn't an object with duplicate fields. This I feel like may not be so hard. I would just need to compare an object with what's in the array before inserting it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to accomplish what you want using `reduce`, along the lines of:

```
reduce .[] as $o
  ({
     people: [],
     terms: [],
     jobs: [],
     locations: []
   }; ......
 )
```

See the jq documentation regarding `reduce`, but in brief, you would replace ...... with the jq instructions for building up your normalized representation.

The easiest way to check for duplicates is probably using `index/1`.  I'd suggest using helper functions (`def ...`) to keep things easy-to-read and easy-to-maintain.

#### Numerical id

If you need to generate a numerical id, then it might be easier to use the idiom:

```
. as $in | reduce range(0;length) as $i (INITIAL; $in[$i] as $o | ......)
```

Comment: I can't seem to get `. as $in | reduce range(0;length) as $i (INITIAL; $in[$i] as $o | ......)` working. I kept getting `INITIAL/0 is not defined at <top-level>`

`reduce` is working nicely so far but I haven't gotten to far into it yet

Comment: "INITIAL" represents your initial value.  You could `def INITIAL: ...;` if you want to use INITIAL.

Comment: ohhhh I see what you meant now. Thanks!